# OpenGL ES 2.0 Vertex position for Overlay

Tags: ios, opengl-es-2.0

Currently I'm drawing with OpenGL ES 2.0 an object with pins in it and display it on a CAEAGLLayer. I'm able to identify objects via color picking.
Now I need to calculate the screen coordinates for the pin's world coordinates in order to draw for example a label on the right position (I want to use cocoa touch components). What would be a proper way to calculate the screen coordinates (hidden objects should be ignored)?
Running through the whole image and use each pixel to perform a color picking on it doesn't sound like the right way to go.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple provides its own flavour of GL math functions : 
See [GLKMathUtils documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GLkit/Reference/GLKMathUtils/Reference/reference.html).

As Lukas pointed out, you can use it to project (world -> screen coordinates) or un-project (screen -> world coordinates)

So, if you're already using GLKit for your matrix transformations, you can use this :

```
GLKVector3 screenPoint = GLKMathProject(modelPoint, modelViewMatrix, projectionMatrix, viewport);
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. But I'm trying to be as platform independent as possible because the code maybe needs to be ported to non apple platforms

Answer (score 0):

I could answer this question myself. On some versions of OpenGL glProject() is available and can be used to calculate the position of a vertex on the screen. Unfortunately this function is not available in OpenGL ES 2.0 so you have to do the calculations yourself or you use a math library like [OpenGL Mathematics](http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.4/index.html) which provides a function glProject():

```
#include "matrix_transform.hpp"
#include "transform.hpp"

vec3 pinScreenPosition = glm::project(vec3(0,0,0), modelMatrix, projectionMatrix, vec4(0, 0, screenDimensions.x * screenScale, screenDimensions.y * screenScale));
```